# How to delete an array list based on key?

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

For instance :

```
Array   
(    
[0] => Array 
 (
     [id] => 23
     [merchant_id] => 23   
 )
[1] => Array 
 (
     [id] => 24
     [merchant_id] => 46  
 )
)
```

I want to delete the list which merchant_id except 46, after the operation:

```
Array   
    (    
    [0] => Array 
     (
         [id] => 24
         [merchant_id] => 46  
     )
    )
```

how the best way to removing this array list?

Comment: Did you try writing something to do this?

Comment: i've been trying using array_filter, diff or any but not get the right ways..

Comment: Hint: [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: can u show me the code?

Comment: @Hallman show me your `array_filter` code and I'll tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Did you try a simple foreach loop with a test and delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get result using `array_filter` as follows

```
// suppose your data is in $data variable
$data = [
  ['id' => 23,
     'merchant_id' => 23],

  ['id' => 23,
     'merchant_id' => 46],

 ];

//return true only if marchant_id == 46 
$filtered_array = array_filter($data,function($datum){
                     return $datum["merchant_id"] == 46;
                  });
```

Comment: I think you mean `== 46` :)

Answer (score 2):

Hi Please check below code

```
$array = array( 
    array('id' => 23, 'merchant_id' => 23),
    array('id' => 24, 'merchant_id' => 46),
    array('id' => 25, 'merchant_id' => 34),
    array('id' => 26, 'merchant_id' => 46),
);

$final = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if($value['merchant_id'] == 46){
        $final[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are struggling with the array functions a simple foreach loop and a test of the field you are interested in would do nicely

```
$A = [  ['id' => 23, 'merchant_id' => 23  ],
        ['id' => 24, 'merchant_id' => 46  ],
        ['id' => 25, 'merchant_id' => 21  ],
        ['id' => 26, 'merchant_id' => 29  ],
    ];


foreach ( $A as $key => $t ) {
    if( $t['merchant_id'] != 46 ){
        unset($A[$key]);
    }
}

print_r($A);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 24
            [merchant_id] => 46
        )

)
```